Update chktex using tlpkg, seems to show the wrong version for chktex?
I'm trying to setup VScode with Latex, and I'm most of the way there, though I keep getting this annoying warning: "chktex: WARNING -- Compilation of regular expression [(?![^][{}]{(?![^][{}]}))[^]]*[ failed with error Invalid preceding regular expression."
It appears that from this post: ChkTeX Regex WARNING "Compilation regular expression" on macOS i need to update chktex. (Worth pointing out this refers to MacOS and I'm on Windows). However, when I open tlmgr to do this, it already displays the most recent version of chktex (1.7.9). When I check which version of chktex I have installed (with "chktex -h") it displays version 1.7.8.
I have verified that I only have one instance of chktex installed (with "where chktex"), and by uninstalling it using tlmgr then reinstalling.
How is this possible? How can I make it update?


I'm having this same issue on macOS, tlmgr says that I'm on 1.7.9 but chktex --version reports 1.7.8

I was worried that maybe the version was just reported wrong in the binary, but I checked that the following still gives a warning, so I think it actually is version 1.7.8 that's being distributed.
% Bug 65500
\begin{tabular}{lp}
1 & foo. \\
2 & bar. \newline kjl
\end{tabular}

I'll try to send an email to their mailing list.

Thanks! For now, I've built chktex from source, and manually replaced the executable and it seems to be working. I had to add an environment variable for chktexrc, and I'm on windows so I had to add lregex to the makefile, and leave HAVE_LIBTERMCAP undefined

It looks like it came out too late for this year, but it should be in next year's release: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2024-October/050870.html
